# How can I play more using relativity?

Tags: relativity, time-dilation

One day I was playing and I thought if I could play more. So I thought of a scenerio in which *I would play for 15 minutes but 5 minutes time would be passed in the whole universe*. So anyone except me won't know about my extra time.

So how can I do that? By using relativity, if I go faster, then my time will go faster which I don't want. I want my time go slower than the whole universe.

Now suppose  if the universe is speeding from me in a certain , than universe's time will go faster which means my time going slower. But if this happens, then it is same that I am also going from the universe in the certain velocity too. So my time will go faster too.

So how can I solve this problem and play more?

Comment: your solution works if you properly think about frames of reference

Comment: @Cursed Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The effect of time dilation is same for you too... If the time in your watch is slower than others it also means you are realising time as normal cause your thoughts have also been slowed down with Same ratio.....so you won't be able to play for 15 min in 5 min..
When 2 bodies are moving with relative velocity both thinks other is slower and they are equally right.... But the body which is accelerated to get relative velocity zero will record less time